# How to add data dynamically to mat-table dataSource?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material2, angular5

I have data streaming from backend and i see it printing in console now i am trying to push event to `dataSource` its throwing error dataSource is not defined. Can someone help how to dynamically add data to materialize table ?

stream.component.html

```
<mat-table #table [dataSource]="dataSource"></mat-table>
```

stream.component.ts

```
import {
    Component,
    OnInit
} from '@angular/core';
import {
    StreamService
} from '../stream.service';
import {
    MatTableDataSource
} from '@angular/material';
import * as io from 'socket.io-client';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-stream',
    templateUrl: './stream.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./stream.component.css']
})
export class StreamComponent implements OnInit {
    displayedColumns = ['ticketNum', "assetID", "severity", "riskIndex", "riskValue", "ticketOpened", "lastModifiedDate", "eventType"];
    dataSource: MatTableDataSource < Element[] > ;
    socket = io();

    constructor(private streamService: StreamService) {};

    ngOnInit() {
        this.streamService.getAllStream().subscribe(stream => {
            this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(stream);
        });
        this.socket.on('newMessage', function(event) {
            console.log('Datasource', event);
            this.dataSource.MatTableDataSource.filteredData.push(event);
        });
    }
}


export interface Element {
    ticketNum: number;
    ticketOpened: number;
    eventType: string;
    riskIndex: string;
    riskValue: number;
    severity: string;
    lastModifiedDate: number;
    assetID: string;
}
```

Answer (score 56):

I have found a solution for this problem, basically if you do:

`this.dataSource.data.push(newElement); //Doesn't work`

But if you replace the complete array then it works fine. So your final code must be :

```
this.socket.on('newMessage', function(event) {
    const data = this.dataSource.data;
    data.push(event);
    this.dataSource.data = data;
});
```

You can see the issue here -> https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/8381

Comment: S/O Review: Please try to add some context to your link. Simply posting links does not add value to your answer. Try to look through the issue and summarize the relevant pieces in your answer. Always try to be as comprehensive as necessary. It may also benefit the asker if you explain your code. Code blocks like this, unfortunately, encourage copy/pasta behavior from future viewers. We want S/O users to gain knowledge here; so if you've got it, share it!

Comment: cleaner and more elegant way:
 ``this.dataSource.data = { 
            ...this.dataSource.data,
            event
}``

Comment: use `this.table.renderRows()`

Comment: this.dataSource.data = [ ...this.dataSource.data, event ]

Comment: that's not a bug, dataSource has to be treathed as immutable.

Answer (score 16):

Here is a very simple and easy solution:

```
displayedColumns = ['ticketNum', 'assetID', 'severity', 'riskIndex', 'riskValue', 'ticketOpened', 'lastModifiedDate', 'eventType'];
dataSource: any[] = [];

constructor() { 

}

ngOnInit() {

}

onAdd() {  //If you want to add a new row in the dataSource
   let model = { 'ticketNum': 1, 'assetID': 2, 'severity': 3, 'riskIndex': 4, 'riskValue': 5, 'ticketOpened': true, 'lastModifiedDate': "2018-12-10", 'eventType': 'Add' };  //get the model from the form
   this.dataSource.push(model);  //add the new model object to the dataSource
   this.dataSource = [...this.dataSource];  //refresh the dataSource
}
```

Hope this will help :)

Comment: tried almost every solution, but this is over all other solution.. thanks

Comment: Very handfull and cleaver solution... best way for solving

Answer (score 15):

The following solution worked for me:

```
this.socket.on('newMessage', function(event) {
    this.dataSource.data.push(event);
    this.dataSource.data = this.dataSource.data.slice();
});
```

---

Another solution would be calling the `_updateChangeSubscription()` method for the MatTableDataSource object:

```
this.socket.on('newMessage', function(event) {
    this.dataSource.data.push(event);
    this.dataSource._updateChangeSubscription();
});
```

This method:

> /**
>        Subscribe to changes that should trigger an update to the table's rendered rows. When the changes occur, process the current state of the filter, sort, and pagination along with the provided base data and send it to the table for rendering.
>        */

Comment: `this.dataSource.data = this.dataSource.data.slice();` is unnecessary and can actually break the connection the dataSource has with the underlying layer.  You can trigger it with `this.dataSource.data = this.dataSource.data;`, it doesn't have to be (and shouldn't be) via a slice / i.e. new array.

Comment: `this.dataSource._updateChangeSubscription()` works for me

Answer (score 9):

from the [docs](https://material.angular.io/components/table/overview)

> Since the table optimizes for performance, it will not automatically check for changes to the data array. Instead, when objects are added, removed, or moved on the data array, you can trigger an update to the table's rendered rows by calling its renderRows() method.

So, you can use ViewChild, and refreshRow()

```
@ViewChild('table', { static: true }) table;
  add() {
    this.dataSource.data.push(ELEMENT_DATA[this.index++]);
    this.table.renderRows();
  }
```

I put together an example in [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-x2cra6?file=app%2Ftable-basic-example.ts)

Comment: Can't upvote this one enough! Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

You could also use the ES6 spread operator or `concat` if you are not using ES6+ to assign the `dataSource` data to a new array.

**In ES6+**

```js
this.socket.on('newMessage', function(event) {
    this.dataSource.data = [...this.dataSource.data, event];
});
```

**ECMAscript version 3+**

```js
this.socket.on('newMessage', function(event) {
    this.dataSource.data = this.dataSource.data.concat(event);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I was stuck in same problem while creating select row and apply some action over rows data. This solution for your problem

```
imports..................
import { MatTableDataSource } from '@angular/material';
@component({ ...

export class StreamComponent implements OnInit {
// Initialise MatTableDataSource as empty
dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<Element[]>();

constructor() {}
...
// if you simply push data in dataSource then indexed 0 element remain undefined
// better way to do this as follows
 this.dataSource.data = val as any;

  // for your problem

   ngOnInit() {
  // ** important note .... I am giving solution assuming the subscription data is array of objects. Like in your case stream and in second event(parameter as callback)
    this.streamService.getAllStream().subscribe(stream => {
       // do it this way
        this.dataSource.data = stream as any;
     // note if you simply put it as 'this.dataSource.data = stream' then TS show you error as '[ts] Type 'string' is not assignable to type '{}[]''
    });
    this.socket.on('newMessage', (event) => {
        console.log('Datasource', event);
          // for this value
       // this.dataSource.MatTableDataSource.filteredData.push(event);   // I couldn't get what you are doing here 
     // SO try to explain what you are getting in this callback function val as event parameter ????????????????? 
     // but you can get it this ways

       this.dataSource.filteredData = event as any;
    });
  }
```

Hope this will help you . If you have any question just ping me.

Answer (score 0):

For me, nothing of these answers didn't work.
I had an observable that I subscribe to get new data.
the only solution that works for me was:

```
 this.dataService.pointsNodesObservable.subscribe((data) => {
  this.dataSource = new InsertionTableDataSource(this.paginator, this.sort, this.dataService);
  this.dataSource.data = data;
});
```

render like a charm!

Comment: This is an incomplete answer, no dataService component included, and violates SO standards.

Answer (score 0):

Insert the element at the beginning or any position you want then call the change subscription method of Mat Table dataSource. Here is the code.

```
this.dataSource.data.unshift(newItem);
this.dataSource._updateChangeSubscription();
```