# Refresh angular mat table dynamically by adding a row?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I know that there have been answers on this subject, despite everything, I struggle to add a new row to a material datasource. Here’s the code I’m trying to make works:

ts:

```
  public dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.piecesJointes);
  public piecesJointes: any[] = [];

  public refresh(): void {
      const pjFinal = { libelle: 'testLibelle', nom: 'testNom };
      this.piecesJointes.push(pjFinal);
      this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.piecesJointes);
      console.log(this.dataSource) // display the correct dataSource
  }
```

this refresh() method is called by a fileSelected event in HTML:

```
(fileSelected)="refresh()"
```

And here's the material table:

```
  <table
    mat-table
    [dataSource]="dataSource"
    class="mat-elevation-z8 demo-table"
  >
    <!-- libelle Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="libelle">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>
       column1
      </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{ element.libelle }}</td>
    </ng-container>

    <!-- nom doc Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="nomDocument">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>
        column2
      </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{ element.nom }}</td>
    </ng-container>

    <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumnsJustifs"></tr>
  </table>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple way.

```
public refresh(): void {
   const pjFinal = { libelle: 'testLibelle', nom: 'testNom' };
   this.piecesJointes.push(pjFinal);
   // assign new data to dataSource.data
   this.dataSource.data = this.piecesJointes;
}
```

Comment: Get the table using `@ViewChild(MatTable) table` and use `this.table.renderRows()`, see, e.g. this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47581267/how-to-add-data-dynamically-to-mat-table-datasource/56948608#56948608)